# Get path of image in specified bundle

Tags: symfony

In my bundle I have a `Resources/public/images/image.jpg` file.

This image is accessible via `http://localhost/bundles/mybundle/images/image.jpg`

How can I get this `/bundles/mybundle` prefix from a controller?
I want to be able to generate the path to the public file without hardcoding `/bundles/mybundle` prefix.

Comment: Try trimming into segments of array. Then use it with array index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create a service which would do this

## Create the service

The main responsibility of this class, is to get the default web path of *any* bundle for *any* resource.
As defined in [`assets:install`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/AssetsInstallCommand.php#L90) command, relative paths for each bundle are expected to be `/bundles/foobar/` for a given `FooBarBundle`

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\WebPathResolver**</kbd>

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\BundleInterface;

class WebPathResolver
{
    /**
     * Gets the prefix of the asset with the given bundle
     *
     * @param BundleInterface $bundle Bundle to fetch in
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @return string Prefix
     */
    public function getPrefix(BundleInterface $bundle)
    {
        if (!is_dir($bundle->getPath().'/Resources/public')) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                'Bundle %s does not have Resources/public folder',
                $bundle->getName()
            ));
        }

        return sprintf(
            '/bundles/%s',
            preg_replace('/bundle$/', '', strtolower($bundle->getName()))
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @param BundleInterface $bundle   Bundle to fetch in
     * @param string          $type     Which folder to fetch in (image, css..)
     * @param string          $resource Resource (image1.png)
     *
     * @return string Resolved path
     */
    public function getPath(BundleInterface $bundle, $type, $resource)
    {
        $prefix = $this->getPrefix($bundle);

        return sprintf('%s/%s/%s', $prefix, $type, $resource);
    }
}
```

## Declare it in your service.yml

Nothing special, but an usual service

<kbd>**@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    acme_foo.webpath_resolver:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\WebPathResolver
```

## Usage

You can then use it in your controller like this

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\Controller\BarController::bazAction**</kbd>

```
$bundle = $this->get('http_kernel')->getBundle('AcmeFooBundle');
$path   = $this->get('acme.webpath_resolver')->getPath($bundle, 'image', 'foo.png');

echo $path; // Outputs /bundles/acmefoo/image/foo.png
```

Comment: But why passing the bundle name as an argument as it can be automatically retrieved ? (see my answer) It could be improved with a `getCurrentBundle()` function or something like this your service, no ?

Comment: @COil I explained some caveats of your answer. Adding a method `getCurrentBundle` to this would add a `Request` dependency. (I expect you meant *"getCurrentControllerBundle"*)

Comment: @Touki Ok, one more thing, why not also testing the image existence? (like the resource dir)

Comment: @COil You could, by adding `if (!file_exists(sprintf("%s/Resources/public/%s/%s", $bundle->getName(), $type, $resource))) { throw new \InvalidArgumentException; }` to the `getPath` method

Answer (score 1):

You use assets in templates, like this:

```
{% image '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

or directly in src:

```
<img src="{{ asset('@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg') }}" alt="Example" />
```

In css files you need to use relative paths.

From controller you can get full path in the same way by:

```
$this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg');
```

Comment: Ok, thanks - but how can I get the result path in controller ?

Comment: @hsz I've edited my post by this, but I don't see the point why do you need it in controller.

Comment: It returns `/@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg`

Comment: The point is to return default avatar image if not found Google's one. So instead of providing avatar's url, I want to return url to a local image, not just filename but whole web path.

Comment: It will be better to create a helper for twig which will provides you the image. In your case, when you get the image from controller, you will need to go through whole collection twice - once in controller, and one more again in template.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this, but is assumes the path is the lowercased bundle name.

```
    $controller = $request->attributes->get('_controller');
    $regexp = '/(.*)\\\Bundle\\\(.*)\\\Controller\\\(.*)Controller::(.*)Action/';
    preg_match($regexp, $controller, $matches);
    $imagePath = '/bundles/'. strtolower($matches[2]). '/images/image.jpg';
```

Comment: This solution has several issues. 1. You depend on Controller namespaced like `Foo\Bundle\Anything\Controller\BarController` which is wrong. A bundle could be named `Foo\Bar\FoobarBundle` then your pattern wouldn't match. Moreover a controller [can be defined as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) and nothing forces you to suffix your controller with `Controller`, nor suffix action with `action`. 2. You expect the request variable to be defined, which might not exists (e.g: Usage in `Console`)

Comment: OK Ok I understand but I assume here that all bundles and actions names are consistent for a given project which is usually the case.